# ALU once compiled giving errors of missing source signal?

Tags: digital-logic, intel-fpga

This is ALU, not sure whether if it is all properly connected but all blocks are the correct ones. This has 3 4 bit latch registers, 5 2:1 ultiplexers, 4 4 bit adders. Can anyone help me?
The problems shown are: he OP's picture shows these error messages: Port "D" of type DFF of instance "inst6" is missing source signal Port "Cin" of type Everything on instance "inst14" is missing source signal.

[image]

Comment: What is your specific error message or question?

Comment: I'm getting these errors, and i dont know how i'm meant to fix it. http://imgur.com/0nrfyjh

Comment: Edit that into your question as text, not an image.

Comment: The OP's picture shows these error messages:
Port "D" of type DFF of instance "inst6" is missing source signal
Port "Cin" of type Everything on instance "inst14" is missing source signal

Comment: This is a great example of why VHDL and Verilog are preferred over schematic entry. The instances mentioned in the error log do indeed look like they have some incorrect connections. Recommend zoom in, disconnect, and carefully re-connect those wires.

Answer (score 1):

The error log references these two instances, and from the screen shot of the schematic it looks like there are indeed some problems with those connections.

No connection on port D of inst6:

[image: inst6 port D connection issue]

Looks like port Cin on inst14 isn't right either, that connection doesn't line up. Even though visually it looks close, trust the netlist. Better delete that wire and re-connnect it, just to be sure.

[image: inst14 port Cin connection issue]

One of the reasons we use VHDL and Verilog instead of schematic capture, is that it's very easy to miss these kinds of connection errors. A missing tie-dot, an unconnected port, an irregular or misleadingly routed trace just doesn't stand out from an array of nearly identical boxes. This isn't just due to inexperience: I've seen professionals make the same type of mistake in schematic entry.

(Another reason is since VHDL and Verilog are text, these file formats work well with source code control tools like Subversion or Git. For larger projects this becomes very important.)